# No puedo iniciar comandos en spark-shell con scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Uso cmd de  win 10, llamo a spark-shell, se ejecuta spark y estoy en la linea de comandos bajo scala. Despues, al tratar de ejecutar cualquier comando que sea, me aparece esto:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\histe\.scala_history (Acceso denegado)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at scala.reflect.io.File.outputStream(File.scala:66)
        at scala.reflect.io.File.writer(File.scala:74)
        at scala.reflect.io.File.bufferedWriter(File.scala:81)
        at scala.reflect.io.File.bufferedWriter(File.scala:79)
        at scala.reflect.io.File.appendAll(File.scala:93)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.FileBackedHistory$class.append(FileBackedHistory.scala:46)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.JLineHistory$JLineFileHistory.append(JLineHistory.scala:50)
        at 
.....
```

(Es un problema de permisos al parecer, pero soy administrador. Si se ejecuta pyspark, espero puedan ayudarme, ya que mis conocimientos en computación no son muy buenos)

Comment: Supongo que el usuario `histe` es el que ejecuta el shell. ¿Cómo invocas el shell? ¿Existe la carpeta `C:\Users\histe`? ¿A qué viene lo de ejecutar `pyspark` en la pregunta?

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta. Una disculpa, pues no pude darle seguimiento a mi publicacion. Ejecuto en la consola CMD de win10 "C:\spark\bin> spark-shell"  tengo la configuración: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M -Xms512M   .... histe es una carpeta de usuario, registrado en win10 como administrador, que por alguna razon a pesar de ya estar registrado como adm, tiene estos problemas de permiso. hay forma de que yo pueda menear .scala_history a otro lugar que no sea la carpeta de usuario "histe" ? mencione lo de pyspark, pues en ambiente python para spark ejecutado en CMD, si funciona

Comment: El fichero `.scala_history` lo puedes borrar sin ningún problema. Lleva un historial de los comandos introducidos en la línea de comandos de `scala` por si quieres revisarlos o volverlos a ejecutar. No es necesario para que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta varias cosas al momento de formular tu pregunta:

1. en primera instancia, debes validar que scala (solamente scala) funciona bien y te permite ejecutar comandos desde el CMD.
2. en la instalación de spark, debes validar la adición de las diferentes variables de entorno que son requeridas para la ejecución desde el CMD (creación del SPARK_HOME) y la adición al path del bin de spark para poder correr "spark-shell".

¡Espero te sirva!